# selector en script de R

Tags: r, script, tidyverse

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de introducir algún selector en un script de R. Intento explicarme. Estoy haciendo un script y quiero que, a mitad del mismo, después de haber completado todo lo anterior, pare y me pregunte cómo quiero continuar, y entonces me arroje en un seleccionable, las diferentes opciones posibles. Así, yo elegiría una, y el script continuaría solo con lo que yo le he indicado.

Gracias.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con if() y else. 
Si sucede tal o cual cosa has tal o cual cosa, y si no es así, lo otro. Y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Hola, @césarhuamanininahuanca No es eso lo que preciso. Me explico. Tengo un archivo csv que hay que limpiar. Primero utilizo un script para ello. Una vez este script acaba, dependiendo lo que yo necesite hacer en ese momento, lanzo un script diferente u otro. Lo que yo quiero es unir todos esos scripts en uno solo. Cuando haga el primer paso, quiero que el script se pare y me pregunté qué deseo hacer entonces. Entonces yo selecciono una de las opciones y el script continua. Entiendo que hay que hacerlo con IF o similar. Pero no sé cómo hacer que me pregunte con qué opción quiero continuar.

Comment: Quizas puedes compartir tu codigo o una muestra para tener una idea más clara de lo quieres lograr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que mencionas, utiliza `readline()` y, en base a la respuesta del usuario, determina el procedimiento a seguir con `switch()` o `if/else`, por ejemplo:

```
valor = sample(1:100, 1)

cat(paste0('El valor obtenido es: ', valor,'. ¿Qué desea hacer?\n',
           '1: calcular el cuadrado\n',
           '2: calcular el cubo\n',
           '3: calcular la raíz cuadrada\n'))

respuesta = readline(prompt = 'Ingrese su respuesta: ')

res = switch(respuesta,
  '1' = valor^2,
  '2' = valor^3,
  '3' = sqrt(valor),
  'Opción no válida'
)

cat(paste0('El resultado es: ', res))
```